# QtButton and Qtimer in python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have this code almost where i want it in terms of the code.  Im looking to have this script refresh every minute and also have a button to manually refresh.  The button is already there but doesnt seem to work as desired.  I want it to redraw or refresh the infomation in the widget.

Button Code:

```
bottom2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Refresh") 
#bottom2.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
#bottom2.setWordWrap(True)
bottom2.clicked.connect(InfoCenter)
```

Timer Code:

```
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
QtCore.QTimer.connect(timer, QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), self, QtCore.SLOT("func()"))
timer.start(6000)
```

Full Code:

```
 import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QApplication, QSplitter, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QColor, QPixmap, QIcon
import Adafruit_DHT
import urllib2
from wunderground import high_0, low_0, conditions_0
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

sensor_args = { '11': Adafruit_DHT.DHT11,
                '22': Adafruit_DHT.DHT22,
                '2302': Adafruit_DHT.AM2302 }

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)


temp = 'Temp={0:0.1f}*  Humidity={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity)

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://partner.mlb.com/partnerxml/gen/news/rss/bos.xml').read())

title = soup.find('item').title
desc = soup.find('item').description
url = soup.find('item').guid



temperature = temperature * 9/5.0 + 32




class InfoCenter(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(InfoCenter, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)


        self.outsidetemp = QLabel("Todays High:{}\nTodays Low:{}\nConditions:{}".format(high_0,low_0,conditions_0),self)
        self.outsidetemp.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)


        self.insidetemp = QLabel('Temperature:{:0.1f}F\nHumidity:{:0.1f}%'.format(temperature,humidity),self )
        self.insidetemp.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)

        self.mlbnews = QLabel("Redsox News \nTitle: %s\nSummary: %s " % (title.text, desc.text), self) 
        self.mlbnews.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.mlbnews.setWordWrap(True)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Refresh") 
        self.button.clicked.connect(InfoCenter)

        splitter1 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter1.addWidget(outsidetemp)
        splitter1.addWidget(insidetemp)

        splitter2 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        splitter2.addWidget(splitter1)
        splitter2.addWidget(mlbnews)
        splitter2.addWidget(button)


        hbox.addWidget(splitter2)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QSplitter')
        self.show()

        #color widget code
        palette = self.palette()
        role = self.backgroundRole()
        palette.setColor(role, QColor('black'))
        self.setPalette(palette)
        outsidetemp.setStyleSheet("QLabel {color:yellow}")
        insidetemp.setStyleSheet("QLabel {color:yellow}")
        mlbnews.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: black; color:white}")

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def refreshLabels(self):
    self.outsidetemp.setText('Temperature:{:0.1f}F\nHumidity:{:0.1f}%'.format(temperature,humidity),self )

    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.refreshLabels)    
    timer.start(5000)
    print 'done'




def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = InfoCenter()
    app.exec_()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**UPDATED CODE**

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Nothing happens? Be more specific.

Comment: Isn't the `funct()` slot missing from `InfoCenter`? What will be called when the timer triggers? Also, on slots, won't `button.clicked.connect(InfoCenter)` will create another instance of `InfoCenter`? Was this intended?

Comment: Also, you are creating a bunch of `QFrames` and then immediately creating another widget with the exact same name.  All those `QFrames` aren't being added to any of the layouts.

Comment: No this was not intended.  I have corrected that issue.  But still does not seem to be refreshing.  I think my issue is that when the app loads it pulls the data and stores it in the variable but when the timer refreshes it is only refreshing the global variable that is already stored.  Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're passing a string to the `QLabel` constructor.  It doesn't recompute the string again when you refresh it.  You'll need to create a refresh function that will recompute the string again.

Comment: I also fixed the qframe issue.  Dont know why i did that haha

Comment: @BrendanAbel Would you or could you show me what you mean by that? How would this look for my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you'll need to store references to your widgets (notice `self`)

```
self.outsidetemp = QLabel(...)
```

You should probably do this for all your widgets, depending on the object and the environment you're running in, not storing a python reference to a widget can cause it to become garbage collected, and you may get errors.

You can also use the new-style signal syntax which is much cleaner

```
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.refreshLabels)
```

Then create a function that will update the labels, connect the `timeout` signal to that.

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def refreshLabels(self):
    self.outsidetemp.setText("Todays High:{}\nTodays Low:{}\nConditions:{}".format(high_0,low_0,conditions_0))
```

I will also add the obligatory warning that using global variables here is probably not the best way to do this.  How are you updating the global variables?  Instead of using a QTimer, why not just have the process that is updating the global variables update the widget?

Comment: OK thank you for that.  I have added this

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def refreshLabels(self):
    self.outsidetemp.setText("Todays High:{}\nTodays Low:{}\nConditions:{}".format(high_0,low_0,conditions_0))
        
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    QtCore.QTimer.connect(timer, QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), self, QtCore.pyqtSlot("func()"))
    timer.start(5000)
    print 'done'

This is not working as intended.

Comment: What you added is not what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Also, "not working as intended" doesn't tell us very much.  It's much more helpful if you describe what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening.

Comment: I added the print done so i know when its run.  other then that its what you wrote copy/paste

Comment: It's hard to tell because code formatting in comments doesn't really work.  Also, youre still using the old timer connect code, and not connecting it to refreshLabels

Comment: Update your question with the code, it doesn't work in commenta

Comment: The `refreshTimer` method is supposed to be a method of the `QWidget` class, not a global function.  The `timer` code was meant to replace your current timer code in the `initUI` method, not go inside the `refreshTimer` method.  Also, the global variables aren't being changed by anything, so the `QLabels`, even if refreshed, aren't going to show different data.

Comment: Ok i have to rework this entire thing.  Thank you for your help.  Its pointless if the text doesnt update to current output.  I see how your answer works though. Still very very green to python and pyqt.